# Want to create a script to grep a particular word from a specific path of remote server using for loop

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/ksh
# set array called nameservers
set -A qaservers l8sita01 l4sita06 l4dvidap2256 l98vidap2256

print -n "\nEnter the Client ID :"
read clientID 

# print all name servers
for i in ${qaservers[@]}
do


ssh "uname -a; grep jms/erms/$clientID /apps/WebSphere/NA70_TBA/config/cells/CellV70_TBA/resources.xml;"

done
```

ERROR

```
ssh: uname -a; grep jms/erms/1212 /apps/WebSphere/NA70_TBA/config/cells/CellV70_TBA/resources.xml;: non-recoverable name resolution failure
ssh: uname -a; grep jms/erms/1212 /apps/WebSphere/NA70_TBA/config/cells/CellV70_TBA/resources.xml;: non-recoverable name resolution failure
ssh: uname -a; grep jms/erms/1212 /apps/WebSphere/NA70_TBA/config/cells/CellV70_TBA/resources.xml;: non-recoverable name resolution failure
ssh: uname -a; grep jms/erms/1212 /apps/WebSphere/NA70_TBA/config/cells/CellV70_TBA/resources.xml;: non-recoverable name resolution failure
```

Comment: u forgot to pass ip/hostname in ssh command

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass IP/hostname in ssh command, hope you are providing those using `for` loop.

```
 ssh "$i" "uname -a;......"
```